# Python Date time Functions - Moving from Pandas to Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I've done some ETL on a file with Pandas.

But this File now is really big (30GB)

So I decided to threat it with Dask Dataframe.

How to replace this Pandas functions to similar Dask Functions?
like: pd.to_datetime , pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('some_big_file.txt', sep = '|', names = names)

date_str1 = df['DT_OP']


##Transforming string to date (original date format = 25032021)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(date_str1.astype(str), format='%d%m%Y')

## Get the first day of month
df['DT_INI'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m01'))

#Current Month
df['MES'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m%Y'))

## Get the Last day of month for given date
df['Date_Month_End'] = df['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=0)
df['DT_FIN'] = df['Date_Month_End'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse dates when reading CSV files with the `parse_dates` argument.

```py
df = dd.read_csv('some_big_file.txt', sep = '|', names = names, parse_dates=["Date"])
```

Here's an example with the New York City taxi data in case others would like a snippet they can replicate on their machine:

```py
df = dd.read_csv(
    "s3://nyc-tlc/trip data/yellow_tripdata_2019-*.csv",
    parse_dates=["tpep_pickup_datetime", "tpep_dropoff_datetime"],
    dtype={
        "payment_type": "UInt8",
        "VendorID": "UInt8",
        "passenger_count": "UInt8",
        "RatecodeID": "UInt8",
        "store_and_fwd_flag": "category",
        "PULocationID": "UInt16",
        "DOLocationID": "UInt16",
    },
    storage_options={"anon": True},
    blocksize="16 MiB",
)
```

Distributed systems generally struggle when working with a single, huge 30GB file.  I'd recommend splitting the file up, so it's more easily read in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The datetime functions do not require communication between partitions/workers, so they can be applied with `.apply` in parallel. The only thing you have to be careful about is potential `meta` ambiguities, so you can provide relevant `meta` option:

```py
##Transforming string to date (original date format = 25032021)
df['Date'] = df['DT_OP'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.astype(str), format='%d%m%Y'), meta=pd.Series())

# you can use the same syntax as pandas, but include it in 
# .apply method of a dask series, df['col_a'].apply(some pandas code)
# or if the column is a datetime object, then you can use .dt
# for example:
df['month_val'] = df['Date'].dt.month
```